# Implementing Hive query in Solr

Tags: mysql, sql, hadoop, solr, hive

My requirements is to execute this query(hive) in solr:

```
select SUM(Primary_cause_vaR),collect_set(skuType),RiskType,market, collect_set(primary_cause) from bil_tos Where skuType='Product' group by RiskType,market;
```

I can implement sum and groupBy operations in solr using StatsComponent concept but I've no idea to implement `collect_set()` in solr.

`Collect_set()` is used in Hive queries.
Please provide me equivalent function for collect_set in solr or links or how to achieve it.
 It'd be a great help.

Comment: Can anyone please reply to this?